# OpenGL: rubber bands in Windows Vista/7

Tags: opengl, windows-7, windows-vista, rubber-band

I've been looking for any solution to draw rubber bands and cursors via OpenGL without redrawing whole window in Windows Vista/7, but can't find anything suitable. Overlay plane approach doesn't seem to be supported widely on all videocards, especially when it comes to dual screen rendering. I found a [solution](http://pollutingtheweb.blogspot.com/2009/03/proper-opengl-rubberband-in-vista-and.html) that suggests manipulating front and back buffer, but comments state that in Windows Vista/7 front buffer manipulations tend to fail on some systems. Simple XOR-ing is not suitable, because cursor and rubber-band colors need to be independent from underlying image colors. Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could experiment with reading back the buffer (or just parts of it) before drawing the rubber band and use that to fill in behind it.  Caveat: Some cards have lousy readback performance so you'd need to test on a variety of cards.